# Is the statement readable

Tags: essay

This is not a proof reading request, I would just like to know whether the statements are readable or at least correct in structure before I would submit it.

"Prescriptions hold no metaphysical substance to identify a man being a sinner. It does not exist as the truth of nature, but only the failure to do what is prescribed. What is normative does not give any account for inherency, truth, or permanency to nature. 
Such language indicating pure value as goodness and evil cannot be tested. Goodness and evil can exist only objectively and not prescriptively.  So for goodness and evil to exist it requires not to be reminded to be done, because he is already observing such."

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is too localized. Checking for readability and structure is requesting us to edit your snippet for you. That's not what Writers.SE does - we're for specific questions that can be answered and problems that can be solved, not for general reviews and revisions of your writing.

Answer (score 2):

I can't make sense of this.  Each sentence but the last seems grammatical, but I don't understand what any sentence means. I don't know what the word "it" refers to in either the second sentence or the last. I don't know what person "he" refers to.

Perhaps some additional context would help me understand this, but I can't make sense of it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Dale; this is so disjointed as to be incoherent. The paragraph needs some context and your sentences need to be simpler and more straightforward.